# Stream data in VP9, VP8 or H.264 data but store it on AWS in .mov format in s3 buckets

Tags: opencv, h.264, video-compression, vp9

I am able to collect frames from RTSP camera using the below code. But need help with storing the data in S3 buckets as a video file. But storing frames takes up lot of storage space.

How do platforms like youtube store the streaming data? How to stream data in VP9, VP8 or H.264 data but store it on AWS in .mov format?

Need to reduce network usage and storage usage.

```
        def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Set camera config object to 'src' variable

        # Create CV2 stream object
        self.camera = src['rtsp_link']
        self.capture = cv.VideoCapture(self.camera)

        # Queue created
        self.q = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)

        # Camera id that maps to sqlite table name
        self.cam_id = src['cam_id']

        # Lower Frames per second reduces network usage and CPU/Memory
        self.resize = (int(self.capture.get(3)/src['resize_factor']),
                       int(self.capture.get(4)/src['resize_factor']))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

        self.msgBody = {}

        print("Program initialized")
        self.debug_flag = 0

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
                while not self.status:
                    print("Video Stream could not read at: {}".format(time.time()))
                    self.capture.release()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    try:
                        self.capture = cv.VideoCapture(self.camera)
                        if self.capture.isOpened():
                            print("Video stream reconnected")
                            (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
                    except:
                        print("Unable to reconnect to camera stream. Alert!")

                    pass
                if not self.q.empty():
                    try:
                        # Discard previous (unprocessed) frame
                        self.q.get_nowait()
                    except queue.Empty:
                        print("No frames in queue.")
                        pass
                self.q.put(self.frame)
                if self.debug_flag:
                    print("Queue updated.")
```

wondering if this would help

```
cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(‘H’,’2′,’6′,’4′)
```

Comment: I could create a .mov file on the local system using the OpenCV cv2.VideoWriter and then store this file in S3 every few minutes. This probably will still increase my storage usage and network use when there isn't too many changes in a frame. Or save file and create a new when file size is larger than some value. Would like to know if there is anything better than this approach.